# How to calculate the sum of numbers which are each increased exponentially?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, actionscript

My maths is terrible (sorry!) I cannot work out what should be a simple equation for a game of mine.

In the game, I have a price for an item which you can purchase an unlimited amount of times - each time you buy it, the price goes up.

Let's say the item costs $5 to buy. Here, I'll buy it 10 times:
5+20+45+80+125+180+245+320+405+500 = $1925 total cost to buy 10 times.

What I am trying to accomplish next, is to provide Buy x10, Buy x20, etc. buttons which will work out the cost for buying it 10 times in one go.

Here's my code currently which will result in the above prices:

```
    public function CalcuatePrice(timesAlreadyPurchased:Number,timesToBuy:int=1):Number {
        var price:Number;
        var basePrice:Number = 5;
        var multiplier:Number;

        //Always need at least 1 (items actually start at purchased 0 times)
        timesAlreadyPurchased += 1;

        //Apply iterations
        if (timesToBuy!=1){
            multiplier = (timesToBuy * (timesToBuy + timesAlreadyPurchased)) / 2;
        } else {
            multiplier = timesAlreadyPurchased; 
        }

        price = basePrice * multiplier;

        return price;
    }
```

Currently, this will only work when timesToBuy is 1. The issue is on line:

```
multiplier = (timesToBuy * (timesToBuy + baseMultiplier)) / 2;
```

I'm just unsure what equation to use to get "timesToBuy = 10", to return a value of $1925 when "timesAlreadyPurchased = 0".

Additionally - anyone know what this type of equation is called in Mathematics? Sum of exponential series perhaps? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an arithmetic progression.

---

The price increases by 15, 25, 35, 45 etc, so the price of the `n`-th buy can be expressed as a recurrence relation:

[image]

Solve this by substitution:

[image]

Nice simple expression. Last step used a formula from [here](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalNumbers.htm). e.g. for `n = 3` (the 3rd buy) the price is `5 * 3^2 = 45` as expected.

---

To get the total price, of course just sum these up:

[image]

Using another formula from the same page linked above.

Test for 5 buys:

- Original: `5 + 20 + 45 + 80 + 125 = 275`
- Formula: `5 / 6 * 5 * 6 * 11 = 275`

---

Update – formula in "pseudocode":

```
price = (5.0 / 6.0) * timesToBuy * (timesToBuy + 1) * (2 * timesToBuy + 1);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the detailed reply. Unfortunately I don't really know how to read what you've written, I only did very basic maths in school! Is there any chance you could write this in pseudocode or something like: "multiplier = (timesToBuy * (timesToBuy + baseMultiplier)) / 2;" ?

Comment: @Joe I'll write the code equivalent although I have no idea what your "baseMultiplier" is

Comment: Thank you! baseMultiplier is actually exactly the same as "timesAlreadyPurchased" really - didn't notice that in my code! I'll adjust my code above.